# Variable repeat error?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

Why am I getting a compile-time error in the following code?

```
private static void phi(int n){
    if(n > 1000)
        for(int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
            //do something
    else
        for(int i = 35; i <= n; i += 90)
            //do something
}
```

The error says

> java:22: error: variable `i` is already defined in method `phi(int)`

But according to me, at any scenario, either `if statement` or `else statement` will be executed, but **never both will be executed at the same time**.

Is this a loophole in `Java`'s compilation techniques or is my method wrong?

---

## EDIT 2

Brackets seem to have fixed the problem. Thanks a lot blackbelt.

---

**EDIT 1**

Double parenthesis doesn't seem to be a reason as I still get an error after removing the parenthesis. In fact the double parenthesis got added by mistake.

Comment: if((n > 1000)  you have an exrta bracket in here? also, check the answer out in this question in relation to "either if statement or else statement will be executed" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one line after the `if` and before the `else`, so you have to use braces to get desired behaviour, not necessary in `for` statement, but mandatory in the `if` in this case.

Also, as [@Joseph82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584654/joseph82) pointed... there is an extra `(` in the first `if`!

```
private static void phi(int n){
    if(n > 1000) {
        for(int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
            //do something
    } else {
        for(int i = 35; i <= n; i += 90)
            //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It is wrong. the problem are the two brackets here: `if((n > 1000)` . Simple remove the first one

Answer (score 1):

Remove an extra `(` from `if((n > 1000)` and use [Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) and Curly Braces.